# cant change font on openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

i am trying to make an automated xlsx document creator, for this i want to make some of the cells to have bold font, this is part of the code i use

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl.styles.colors import Color
wb_orden = load_workbook(filename = 'resg.xlsx')
ws_orden = wb_orden["Resguardo"]
italic24Font = Font( size = 24, italic = True, bold = True)
ws_orden['A6'] = "hsadgfagahgafdhg"
ws_orden['A6'].font = italic24Font
NAME = "generated/"+"res_"+order+".xlsx"
wb_orden.save(filename = NAME)
```

but when i see the xlsx file the A6 cell is changed to hsadgfagahgafdhg, but it isn't bold. thanks for reading i hope you can help me whit this

i also tried this but still not working

```
ws_orden['A6'].font = Font(size=23, underline='single', color='FFBB00', bold=True, italic=True)
```

Comment: That's interesting. It works for me if I open the xlsx in libreoffice, but my past experience says that when open in ms office the font really is not changed.

Comment: actually my issue is on reverse, i had the xlsx file that was created on windows, then i tried to edit it on libre office, once the file was saved on ubuntu, the file stops the style changing, now i edited the xlsx on windows's office and now it is working